Reference request: "Higher order eigentuples" as generalized eigenvectors?
I stumbled upon a cute generalization of the eigenvalue problem and would like to know if anybody has seen something like this and can provide references.
The eigenvalue problem for a square matrix $M$ is to find a vector $v\neq 0$ and a scalar $\lambda$ such that $Mv = \lambda v$. Put differently: find the one-dimensional $M$-invariant subspaces and how the matrix acts on them. To make dimensions fit, we can also write the eigenvalue equation as
$$
\underbrace{M}_{n\times n} \underbrace{v}_{n\times 1} = \underbrace{v}_{n\times 1} \underbrace{\lambda}_{1\times 1}.
$$
Here is a generalization of this problem which I haven't seen before: Given a square matrix $M$ of size $n\times n$, find a matrix $V$ of size $n\times 2$ and a matrix $\Lambda$ of size $2\times 2$ such that
$$
MV = V\Lambda.
$$
This is also related to invariant subspaces as the columns of $V$ need to span an $M$-invariant subspace. The analogy with eigenvalues goes a little further. Using the Kronecker product and the column-wise vectorization we can write $MV = V\Lambda$ as
$$
(I_2 \otimes M)\operatorname{vec}(V) = (\Lambda\otimes I_n)\operatorname{vec}(V) 
$$
(with $I_m$ being the $m\times m$ identity) and hence, such a $\Lambda$ has to fulfill that
$$
\det(I_2\otimes M - \Lambda\otimes I_n) = 0.
$$
Of course, this further generalizes to matrix $V$ of size $n\times m$ and $\Lambda$ of size $m\times m$…
Since this seems to be a very natural generalization with implications for matrix computations, I would be surprised if this has not been studied.
(I got interested in this question when I wondered if it is possible to obtain a $\Lambda$ (for given $A$ of size $m\times n$ and a (symmetric) $M$ of size $n\times n$) such that $(A^TA + M)^{-1}A^T = A^T(AA^T + \Lambda)^{-1}$. This always holds for $M = \alpha I_n$ with $\Lambda = \alpha I_m$ but for other $M$ it is necessary that the columns $A^T$ span an $M$-invariant subspace and that $MA^T = A^T\Lambda$.)

Are you sure about that necessary condition in the last line? Surely there are solutions in which the columns of $A^\top$ are not linearly independent, for instance you can take $A$ to be the matrix of all zeros.

Oh, right, thanks! Linear independence does guarantee uniqueness of $\Lambda$ if I am not mistaken.

The observation that $MV = V\Lambda$ is essentially an invariant subspace relation is commonly used in methods to solve algebraic Riccati equations via Hamiltonian matrices; for instance, the Schur method and the matrix sign method. For instance, one can prove that if $M, V, \Lambda$ satisfy that relation (and $V$ has full column rank), then the spectrum of $\Lambda$ is a subset of that of $M$ (with multiplicities); moreover, $\operatorname{Im} V$ can be written as the span of the Jordan chains of $M$ associated to the eigenvalues in $\Lambda$ (if the spectrum of $\Lambda$, $\Sigma(\Lambda)$, is disjoint from $\Sigma(M) \setminus \Sigma(\Lambda)$).
You can find more for instance in the books

Datta, Biswa Nath, Numerical methods for linear control systems. Design and analysis. With CD-ROM., Amsterdam: Elsevier/Academic Press (ISBN 0-12-203590-9/hbk). xxxviii, 695 p. (2004). ZBL1079.65072.

(chapter 13) and

Bini, Dario A.; Iannazzo, Bruno; Meini, Beatrice, Numerical solution of algebraic Riccati equations., Fundamentals of Algorithms 9. Philadelphia, PA: Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (SIAM) (ISBN 978-1-611972-08-5/pbk; 978-1-611972-09-2/ebook). xvi, 250 p. (2012). ZBL1244.65058.

(Disclosure for conflict of interests purpose: the authors of this second book are close colleagues/collaborators of mine.)
The reformulation with Kronecker products does not seem too useful computationally, but similar techniques are used when working with Sylvester equations $AX-XB = C$; here $A$ and $B$ are square but $C$ and $X$ may be rectangular. That equation can be rewritten as a linear system with matrix $I\otimes A - B^\top \otimes I$.

Nice, thanks! Will look up these books. I suspected something like he spectrum of $\Lamda$ being a subset of that of $M$ …

@Dirk Another interesting abstract way to think about it is the following: if you restrict the linear operator $M$ to the invariant subspace $\operatorname{Im} V$, then $\Lambda$ is the matrix that represents the restricted operator in the basis induced by the columns of $V$. In particular, this implies that any eigenvalue of $\Lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $M$.

Let me assume that $M$ is symmetric, then we can work in a basis where it is diagonal, $M=\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots \mu_n)$. I denote the vectors $v_i=V_{i1}$ and $u_i=V_{i2}$, $i=1,2\ldots n$. The $2n$ equations I need to solve for the $2n+4$ elements of $v,u,\Lambda$ are
$$X_i{{v_i}\choose{u_i}}=0,\;\;X_i=\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_i-\Lambda_{11}& - \Lambda_{21} \\
-\Lambda_{12} &  \mu_i-\Lambda_{22}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This problem is heavily underdetermined. For a solution which is not identically zero, set all $v_i,u_i$ to zero except one single $i\equiv i_0$. Then choose $\Lambda$ such that $\det X_{i_0}=0$.

That's not so different than for the eigenvalue problem where one has n equations for n+1 unknowns and the problem is underdetermined by just one. Here we have four and in the general case it should be $m^2$ (number of entries of "eigenmatrices $\Lambda$)

This seems to be equivalent to finding invariant two dimensional subspaces. One way to algebraically describe two dimensional subspaces is the vector space $V'=\Lambda^2V$ (the second wedge product). The action of $M$ on $V$ induces an action on $V'$. Pick a basis for $V$ which induces a basis on $V'$, and then you can express the action induced by $M$ on $V'$ as some matrix $M'$. Now, find the eigenvectors of $M'$, if this is a pure wedge $v\wedge w$, the subspace spanned by $v$ and $w$ is left invariant under $M$ and the eigenvalue is the determinant of the transformation matrix you're looking for. In order to check if a vector $\omega\in \Lambda^2V$ is a pure wedge of two vectors, quadratic equations of the coefficients called the Plucker relations can be checked. This seems annoying to do by hand, but seems doable to code up.

$\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\La\Lambda$

Given a square matrix $M$ of size $n\times n$, find a matrix $V$ of size $n\times 2$ and a matrix $\Lambda$ of size $2\times 2$ such that
$$
MV = V\Lambda.
$$

There may be many such matrices, even with the additional condition that $\La$ be diagonal. E.g., if $u$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $M$ with the corresponding eigenvalues $\la$ and $\mu$, $V$ is the $n\times2$ matrix with columns $u$ and $w$, and $\La$ is the diagonal matrix with $\la$ and $\mu$ on the diagonal, then $MV=V\La$ will hold.
Also, if $u$ and $w$ are "Jordan-form" vectors such that $Mw=\la w$ and $Mu=\la u+w$ for some complex $\la$, if $V$ is the $n\times2$ matrix with columns $u$ and $w$, and if $\La=\begin{bmatrix}\la&0\\1&\la \end{bmatrix}$, then $MV=V\La$ will again hold.
